# ENTER (how to block, getting bottom row)

Tags: jquery

I have a div named as "block".
this is an editable div (contenteditable="true")
when I'm focused this div, if I press ENTER cursor gets bottom row.
I want to block this thing. I want to remove getting bottom row function when I press enter.

is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You want to stop what? What's your JavaScript/jQuery? Your HTML? Can you show us a (minimal/[sscce](http://sscce.org/)) representative [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) (as well as posting the relevant code *here*)?

Comment: Maybe you can catch the Enter key with jQuery/javascript event and prevent it from inserting a new line... (just an idea, never tried it).

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent this by listening to the keydown event and return false.

```
// Replace '#block' with your element ID 
$('#block').on('keydown', function(e){ 
    // e.which returns the keyCode for the key pressed 
    // where '13' is the enter key.
    if(e.which == 13) 
       return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

id or class? Use $('block').last().css('display', 'block');

See http://api.jquery.com/last/

Comment: I strongly doubt that's what the OP means by "block".